# Bootstrap JS: How do I toggle this code?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a snippet of JS that is working with an accordion I have set up. What it does currently is when you click on a heading of the accordion, it opens and auto closes the previous heading that was open. What would I add to this snippet so that I can toggle each heading manually to open and close?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var anchor = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
$(".collapse").collapse('hide');
$("#" + anchor).collapse('show');
</script>
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to make sure previously-expanded accordions collapse whenever you open a new one.  This is the default behavior of Collapse for Bootstrap 3.x and 4.x so I'm not sure what the purpose of your code is... can you elaborate?

Comment: I just realized I posted the wrong snippet. That code was for auto expanding an accordion from clicking on a link from a different page..... what you said is correct, I have that working currently. What I'm trying to do is, if you click on that same header, currently, it does not close if it is open. It only closes if you click on another header. What attribute would I add to the HTML so that it will close by clicking on it- if it's open?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Again you are describing default behavior of Collapse for BS v3 and v4.  Clicking an already-open header will close the panel to which it is associated... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example or https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse for examples.

Comment: What would cause that default behavior to break? I stripped out all my code to trouble shoot and it works perfectly locally but when on my server and then on SharePoint, it doesn't. So something is conflicting with it.

Comment: Without a larger view of your code there is no way for us to know.  It could be anything from a JavaScript conflict to something in your CSS conflicting with the class names Bootstrap is using.

Comment: I'm marking this solved as I just realized something you made me remember. Thank you!